# async-await y worker threads en NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, hilos, async-await, asincronismo

tengo una duda, en NodeJs qué sucede cuando tengo async y await por ejemplo para descarga de archivos pesados, y quiero usar los worker threads, estaría redundando en la funcionalidad si los uso al mismo tiempo para descargar los archivos?, pregunto porque al final async ayuda a precisamente no bloquear el hilo principal, gracias!

Comment: Los `worker_threads` son útiles cuando tienes operaciones intensivas de CPU, pero no son de mucha ayuda en operaciones intensivas de I/O, donde las operaciones asincronas incorporadas en NodeJS realmente destacan sobre `worker_threads`. Traducido de: [NodeJS Threads (Workers)](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads). Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour].